# Resposta da query cheia de line breaks

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Olá, tenho um problema com a resposta do query que fiz a db está cheia de `\n` e `\` . Alguém sabe o que pode ser o problema? Obrigado.

função model, faz a query a db em busca dos produtos adicionados ao carrinho por um determinado user

```
function _get_cart_by_user($id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('cart');
    return $query;

}
```

função do controlador, apenas recebe o resultado do modelo e faz return do mesmo

```
    public function get_cart()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('user_id', TRUE);

        $this->load->model('cart_model');
        $query=$this->cart_model->_get_cart_by_user($id);   

        $result= $query->result();


        var_dump($result);


    }
```

Pedido AJAX, que deveria receber o retorno do controlador e mostrar na console do browser

```
    function addItemToCart(user_id) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: BASE_URL + 'cart/get_cart',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'user_id': user_id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

isto é o resultado do `var_dump` do controlador.

> "array(2) {\n  [0]=>\n  >object(stdClass)#24 (6) {\n    >[\"id\"]=>\n    string(2) >\"16\"\n    [\"user_id\"]=>\n    >string(1) \"5\"\n
>   [\"item_id\"]=>\n    >string(1) \"2\"\n
>   [\"title\"]=>\n    string(4) >\"Buda\"\n    [\"price\"]=>\n    >string(4) \"9.99\"\n
>   [\"image\"]=>\n    string(0) >\"\"\n  }\n  [1]=>\n  >object(stdClass)#25 (6) {\n    >[\"id\"]=>\n    string(2) >\"17\"\n    [\"user_id\"]=>\n    >string(1) \"5\"\n
>   [\"item_id\"]=>\n    >string(1) \"3\"\n
>   [\"title\"]=>\n    string(12) >\"budaoriginal\"\n
>   [\"price\"]=>\n    string(4) >\"9.99\"\n    [\"image\"]=>\n    >string(0) \"\"\n  }\n}\n"

Alguém sabe me dizer o que são esses `\` e `\n`, eu também tentei fazer `json_enconde` (fiz echo do `json_encode` e aparece as `\` ) e passar para o AJAX mas quando faço o console do response apenas aparece "".

Comment: pode usar um Regex para remover os caracteres de escape `\n`

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a tabela ASCII o **\n** significa *new line* (nova linha), e como o browser interpreta o html para montar a DOM o **\n** não surte nenhum efeito diretamente, mas felizmente existe uma tag html `<pre></pre>` que tem essa função de formatar essas quebras de linhas e espaços em branco.

Em seu caso basta utilizar da seguinte forma.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result)
echo "</pre>";
```

Por fim o **\"** na verdade tem a função de indicar que aquela aspa faz parte do conteúdo do código ou da informação e não se trata de uma **aspa** de fechamento.

Para ficar mais claro segue o exemplo:

```
"Abrindo aspas nessa linha
vou ignorar essas aspas \"faço parte do conteúdo\"
Agora nessa linha vou fechar aspas"
```

Espero que tenha te ajudado e ficado claro.

Comment: Então fazer json_encode do result e retornar o mesmo para o Ajax, posteriormente fazer um console.log(JSON.stringify(data)). Isto deveria mostrar uma string com toda a informacão, mas apenas mostra aspas vazias.

Comment: não me parece uma boa ideia gerar uma tag html no php para um retorno ajax, isso deveria ser formatado no javascript do lado cliente

Comment: O que eu tentei foi result() e result_array() depois retornei json_encode do result. No Ajax success fiz o console log do JSON.stringify, mas apenas apareciam aspas vazias. E quando fazia no controlador o var_dump do result e result_array apareciam os tais \n (nova linha) que eu acho n ser normal.

Comment: Já percebi o que estava a fazer errado não é preciso fazer um return para fornecer data ao Ajax. Basta um echo do resultado